# How to switch mailboxes in Mutt?

Tags: mutt

I want to switch between the "Sent" mailbox and the current mailbox. I use the maildir type.

Ideally, there would be a macro bound to a shortcut key that does this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write a macro and bind it to a key, or key sequence. For example, in my `muttrc` I include this line:

```
macro index \Cs  "<change-folder> =JWR/INBOX.Sent<enter>"  "go to Sent Items"
```

It takes me to my Sent items with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>.

You can determine the correct name of the relevant maildir folder by bringing up the prompt with <kbd>c</kbd> and then hitting <kbd>?</kbd> for the list.

Comment: If you want to bind it to a Function key, you'll need to use <F4> - also, are you sure that is the correct path _as mutt sees it_?

Comment: yes, I can do `mutt -f /home/XX/Mail/.Sent`, and that works

Comment: No: follow the advice I provided in my answer and source the correct path from mutt's prompt...

Comment: That worked, just one thing, is it possible to "toggle" between the two mailboxes ?

Comment: There is a [<toggle-mailboxes> call](http://www.elho.net/mutt/maildir/) but I haven't played around with it: so I'm not sure.

Comment: I'll bind two different keys as a temporary solution, thanks anyway

Comment: There's an [artificial one second delay per default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531719/delay-when-switching-mailboxes/531720#531720) when switching mailboxes. To get rid of this, put `set sleep_time = 0` in your muttrc.

Answer (score 7):

[image: mutt sidebar sample screenshot]

The arch wiki has a good section on [enabling and using the TUI sidebar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt#Mutt-Sidebar). You can either set it visible all the time:

```
set sidebar_visible = yes
```

Or bind `sidebar-toggle-visible` to a key. `sidebar-prev` and `sidebar-next` are used to switch the folder selection, and `sidebar-open` opens the selected folder.

Comment: Note that the [TUI sidebar link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt#Sidebar) has since changed.

Answer (score 2):

On my system, I wanted to go back to the INBOX and had to use the following,
Otherwise if I did C? and went to another folder, I couldn't get back to the inbox.

```
macro index <home>  "<change-folder> =INBOX"<enter>
```