# Delay when switching mailboxes

Tags: mutt

I have an issue that occurs each time when switching mailboxes in Mutt:

There's a noticeable delay until the other mailbox is visible, seemingly unconnected to the size of the mailboxes.

Is there anything I can configure in my `muttrc` to speed things up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mutt#Speed_up_folders_switch):

```
set sleep_time = 0
```

Put this in your `muttrc` and the [artificial lag of one second](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#sleep-time) when switching mailboxes is gone.